# DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but ignore a column, using wpdb->prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm experiencing an issue when attempting to insert a row using `$wpdb->prepare()`.

I am able to create a new row, no issues and all seems to be firing well (no errors). The problem arises with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Due to using `$wpdb->prepare`, I am required to use placeholders. What I am looking to achieve if there is a duplicate, is to basically update every column EXCEPT the keys and `date_created_gmt` (I don't want to overwrite this column, as essentially it would become the date it was updated).

What is happening is - in order to update and not get thrown the errors `PHP Notice:  Function wpdb::prepare was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. The query does not contain the correct number of placeholders (2) for the number of arguments passed (3)` I have to include the placeholder, which ultimately overwrites `date_created_gmt`

I am essentially looking for the equivalent of `if ( row_is_duplicate ) { update all columns except 'customer_id' and 'date_created_gmt' }`

What is the correct way to accomplish this, avoiding errors due to the `prepare()` statement?

**The code**

```
function create_customer_data_table(){

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

        global $wpdb;
        $table_name   = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
        $users        = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';

        $wpdb->query(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
            id                  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            customer_id         BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            name                VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,           
            date_created_gmt    DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES $users(ID)
        ) ENGINE = MyISAM
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
        COLLATE = utf8_general_ci"
    );
}

function insert_customer_data_row() {
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';

    $customer_id        = $_POST["customer-id-hidden"];
    $name               = $_POST['name']; //string value use: %s
    $date_created_gmt   = wp_date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //string value use: %s    

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO $tablename
        (`customer_id`, `name`, `date_created_gmt`) 
        VALUES
            (%d, %s, %s)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            customer_id = %d,
            name        = %s,
            date_created_gmt = %s",
            $customer_id,
            $name,
            $date_created_gmt,
            $customer_id,
            $name,
            $date_created_gmt
        );

    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: a quick look at the syntax of an `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` would be a better start

Comment: @RiggsFolly nice catch - this is a short code I wrote to illustrate my problem (my actual problem is a lot more code, not useful) - believe I fixed the syntax. Are you able to help me with the problem?

Comment: From MySQL 8, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should be the standard way of expressing the clause

Comment: @GabrieleSerra receiving ``PHP Notice: Function wpdb::prepare was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement, the `UPDATE` part should contain only the list of fields that you want to update.

Furthermore, you can use the `VALUES(col_name)` function to refer to column values from the `INSERT` portion. In other words, `VALUES(col_name)` refers to the value of `col_name` that would be inserted.

As an example:

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (`customer_id`, `name`, `date_created_gmt`) 
VALUES (1, "John", '2023-01-01')
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE `name` = VALUES(`name`); -- id and date untouched
                                    -- name updated using 'John' as a value
```

Then, your code should be something like this:

```php
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO $tablename
        (`customer_id`, `name`, `date_created_gmt`) 
        VALUES (%d, %s, %s)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            name        = VALUES(`name`)",
            $customer_id,
            $name,
            $date_created_gmt
        );
```

Here above, when the key is not duplicated, it will insert the row; otherwise, when the key is duplicated, all columns except `name` are untouched, and `name` get the value specified in the variable list.

Comment: The issue comes back the same when I try this. I get the notice PHP Notice:  Function wpdb::prepare was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.9.0.) in C:\wamp64\www\development\sns-major-update\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5835

Comment: Are you sure we are referring to the same piece of code? I have a reproducible example that works. The number of arguments in `wpdb::prepare` is correct; the placeholders are there.

Comment: Your comment made me scan all of my code... Your fix was correct, and works great and fixed the problem. The PHP notice that remained was actually being triggered by another ``get_row()`` prepare statement that was calling the values on the front-end. Thanks so much.

Comment: Great. I am happy to hear that. If the answer is working, flag it as accepted, so other users can benefit from it